# Symfony Silex : Runing new Silex project

Tags: sql, database, symfony, orm, silex

I have a Silex project and I want to start understand how that micro framework work, I've configured the database and I don't know how to update the schema with command line. in the json file I have:

> "doctrine/dbal": "2.3.*",
>
> "doctrine/orm": "2.3.*",

any help please ? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK there's no `Console` component included in Silex default package. Consider installing [Console Service Provider](https://github.com/KnpLabs/ConsoleServiceProvider).

Comment: If onwe was to draw a Venn Diagram of "things Silex cares about" and "things the database cares about", there is no overlap between the two circles. Silex handles routing requests to a controller method, and it also includes some integration with the Pimple DI container. Anything else... you need to do yerself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at https://github.com/lyrixx/Silex-Kitchen-Edition this is a sample Silex application which 'classic' web apps needs addressed, such as creating and updating the database schema.